# Is there a C++ equivalent to PHP's var_dump and die?

Tags: c++

I know it's a simple question, but I'm looking to get my C++ groove on. I would imagine some sort of `abort` function could be used. But I don't think that'll return any text like `die('hello');` would.

Comment: So print the text and *then* exit?

Comment: Right, that would be one way to go. Was just wondering if there was a command to do it AND print

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "print a message, then exit" in C or C++. You can quite easily write your own function for `die` (or `panic`, as I prefer to call it), something like:

```
void die(const std::string& msg)
{
    std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Or, if you want to avoid the problems with creating a string, which may fail under low memory conditons:

```
void die(const char *msg)
...
```

(the rest should be the same as above). The drawback here is that you can't trivially concatenate strings, e.g. `die(std::string("Could not open file ") + filename);` won't work with `const char *`.

A function that does `var_dump` is much harder, as there is no direct way to actually fetch the content of a variable of a an arbitrary type, or an array, in C++. You could perhaps do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void var_dump(const T& var)
{
   std::cout << var << endl;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void var_dump(const T (&var)[N])
{
   for(i : var)
   {
      std::cout << i << endl;
   }
}
```

The latter is a bit like this PHP code: `foreach($var as $i) echo $i . "\n";`. And I may have the syntax slightly wrong, not sure.

Comment: I wouldn't use `std::string` here, under failure conditions it is likely to fail even harder.

Comment: @BenVoigt: if "Failure" is out of memory, possibly yes. For most other failures, probably not... I've changed it to `const` reference, which should avoid having to make a copy.

Comment: Also, any failures relating to heap corruption.  For error logging, it's not wise to assume a program with well-defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t recommend calling `std::abort`, `std::exit` or anything like that.

It’s brute-force, and the semantics for proper cleanup are very complicated. You are essentially leaving (at least parts of) your program behind in a very messy state.

A much better way in C++ is to throw an exception which you then catch in `main`:

```
#include <stdexcept>

struct fatal_error : std::logic_error {
    fatal_error(char const* message) : std::logic_error(message) { }
};

int main() try {
    … the normal program flow starts here
} catch (fatal_error const& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Then, instead of `die`, you’d simply say `throw fatal_error("Something went wrong.");`.

Comment: *"throw an exception which you then catch in `main`"* - Er, no. Why unconditionally catch an exception, that you don't know how to handle? No, just let it pass, if you don't know what to do. Incidentally, that's a lot closer to what the OP is asking for. Semantics for uncaught exceptions in C++ are pretty well specified these days.

Comment: @IInspectable When this answer was written, uncaught exceptions led to unspecified or undefined (can't remember which) behaviour and leaked resources. But in addition, no end user wants to be presented with the output from an uncaught exception. Much better to keep control over formatting.

Comment: This answer was written in 2013. Are you implying, that uncaught exceptions caused unspecified or undefined behavior in C++11? I'm not convinced this is correct. If you want control over error reporting, you should set up an uncaught exception filter outside the C++ universe. Depending on the environment, this allows you to gather even more diagnostic information, e.g. the precise location, where the exception was raised. A catch-all handler in `main` won't deliver in that department.

Comment: So honest question: why do you care in what state it leaves your program if you're aborting/exiting anyway?

Comment: @SilverSlash Depends on the state, but some state persists across application starts, of course. E.g. file system changes, or database consistency, etc.

Comment: Exceptions are exceptions, and exiting and exiting. Both have their uses. I don't see why it's better to throw than to exit on a fatal error.

Comment: @einpoklum Doesn’t my answer explain why it’s better? It’s because `std::exit`/`std::abort` does not invoke destructors, and in C++ this is generally not acceptable because destructors can (and frequently *do*) have arbitrary side-effects. Moreover, I’m sure you already know this. C++ is different from other languages (such as Rust) where aborting is generally much safer (though still has its issues). In C++, throwing an exception all the way up the stack effectively has the same effect as aborting, but with none of the drawbacks.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: 1. But it does invoke destructors. At least, exit() does. 2. This is mostly-acceptable, since taking a process down "destructs" everything internal to it: locks, memory allocations and mappings etc.  ... however, there will be the issue of out-of-process "destruction" work, like interaction over the network, files which may need to be removed etc. And then again, that might be an issue in other languages as well.

Comment: @einpoklum (1) Only those of thread-local objects. It doesn’t walk up the call chain and destroy local objects. (2) It really depends, and I don’t agree that this is generally mostly acceptable in C++ — again, because it’s common and expected that destructors in C++ perform arbitrary side-effects, not just “conventional” resource cleanup. Of course this might also be an issue in other languages (as my previous comment also said) but it is especially so in C++. And C++ has a simple remedy: throw an exception instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Can you slightly tweak your answer text so that I can change my vote on it?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you need these equivalents for debugging purpose...

instead of **die()** you may invoke the debugger;

instead of **var_export()** you may inspect your variables content with the debugger.

Comment: Not using VC++. So how would I invoke the debugger?